# What is the best practice in Pentaho DI(Kettle) for converting a csv into a One to Many Relationship

Tags: csv, one-to-many, pentaho, rdbms, kettle

I am new to Pentaho DI(formerly Kettle) and I am tasked with taking CSV data and populating tables in an RDBMS that are in a "One to Many" relationship.

Here is an example of how the CSV data is structured:

```
OrderID,CustomerName, Date,Total Cost,LineItemNumber, LineItemDesc,LineItemQty,LineItemCost
101655,Mary Smith,2016-02-08,6.25,1|2|3|4,Lettuce|Tomatoes|Green Onions|Cucumbers,1|2|4|2,1.00|2.50|0.75|2.00
```

NOTE: the multiple values are seperated by pipes(|)

I need to convert it into the following tables:

[image]

I have been looking into several ways of doing this but didn't want to miss something simple due to my inexperience. Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

I have come up with a solution but it looks awfully complicated.

[image: My Solution]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the **Split fields to Rows** STEP in **PDI**. Give Delimiter as `|` (pipe) and give the column/field that you want to split.

Check the [Pentaho wiki](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Split+field+to+rows) for more.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks Rishu, your solution helped out along with using the Add sequence to facilitate an inner join(see solution above)